# signature_pad canvas does not render inside asp.net form

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Using szimek's signature-pad libraries, I'm trying to embed the canvas into an asp.net form.  When I test, the canvas does not render and viewing the elements shows that the canvas consistently has a height of zero.  If I remove the form tags, it's fine.  Anyone have a suggestion?

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad">
            <div class="signature-pad--body">
                <canvas></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="signature-pad--footer">
                <div class="description">Sign above</div>
                <div class="signature-pad--actions">
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
                        <button type="button" class="button" data-action="change-color">Change color</button>
                        <button type="button" class="button" data-action="undo">Undo</button>
                        <asp:button text="Save" runat="server" cssclass="button save" data-action="save" onclick="Save" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save-png">Save as PNG</button>
                        <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save-jpg">Save as JPG</button>
                        <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save-svg">Save as SVG</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" id="hfSign" runat="server" />
    </form>
    <script src="js/signature_pad.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used Signature Pad before, [Click here to check demo](http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/)

Step 1 : You need to apply height and width to `<canvas>`

```
<canvas id="mySketch" width="500" height="200">
</canvas>
```

Step 2 : You have already a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="hfSign" runat="server" />
```

Step 3 : Fill `canvas` resutl to `hfSign` and convert its value to image using `Convert.FromBase64String()`

Comment: This only seems to work when I don't enclose everything in a form.  The width and height is ignored when in a form.  I'm still getting a zero height.

Comment: It appears that the only way I can get it to show up is to modify the css for .signature-pad--body canvas {} and change the position tag from absolute to relative.  This works in firefox and chrome but not in IE.  IE makes the canvas overlap the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Used an older version of the signature-pad.css and placement is now correct in all browsers.